# Are convolutions in deep learning associative?

Tags: deep-learning, correlation, convolution, mathematics

Let's denote "convolution in deep learing" as "convolution-deep", and "convolution in math or signal processing" as "convolution-math".
As we all know, convolution-deep are actually cross-correlation, and cross-correlation is not associative while convolution-math is associative.
Therefore, is the formulations listed followed true?

Suppose W1 and W2 are weight tensors of two convolution layers or filters for cross-coorelation in sequence, X and Y are the input and output, respectively.

1. Y1=conv-deep( conv-deep(X, W1), W2)==conv-deep(X, conv-deep(W1, W2))?
2. Y2=conv-math( conv-math(X, W1), W2)==conv-math(X, conv-math(W1, W2))?